# ImageMagick resize issue (it is not pixel perfect)

Tags: image, imagemagick

When I run the following command:

convert "test.jpg" -resize 532x308 -quality 85 "output.jpg"

As a result I have output.jpg image with size: 531x308: https://gyazo.com/2741f35488d53e02aa6147a0beecf42e

Why it is not pixel perfect, i.e why output image do not have size 532x308? Or I do not understand something?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to force a specific, exact size and are happy to accept distortions, use:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 532x308\! result.jpg
```

You can omit the backslash if on Windows.

In general, ImageMagick will resize to the nearest proportions to what you request, but **without distorting**. Read the `!` as *"do what I say"* :-)

Comment: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry Shows some of the -resize options